# SQL order by [Order] but group similar items together

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, linq

Sorry if I don't really know the terms for this, I will try to explain this the best I can...

This is what I've got now

```
SELECT * FROM Products ORDER BY [Order]

 Order  ProductId  Color
   1       10      Black
   2       59      Black
   3       10      White
   4       48      Black
```

(the table is simplified, the real table has about 30,000 records)
But this is what I actually want

```
 Order  ProductId  Color
   1       10      Black
   3       10      White
   2       59      Black
   4       48      Black
```

So I want it sorted by [Order], but keep the same ProductId close together, so the 3rd line should move up next to the first, because their ProductId is the same (ie. 10)

Is that even doable?
If it's not possible in SQL Server query, is there any easy way to do it in LINQ perhaps?

Comment: If you want ProductID to be close to each other in that case `48` should be displayed before `59` ?

Comment: I knew some people won't read the question and simply goes "Just order it by ProductID!". That's why I put 10-59-48 hehe

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work, provided you're on a moderately up to date SQL Server:

```
declare @t table ([Order] int not null,ProductId int not null,
                  Color char(5) not null)
insert into @t ([Order],ProductId,Color) values
(1,10,'Black'),
(2,59,'Black'),
(3,10,'White'),
(4,48,'Black')

select * from
(
    select *,MIN([Order]) OVER (PARTITION BY ProductId) as Ord
    from @t
) t
order by Ord,[Order]
```

Which is hopefully readable as what I take your spec to be - for each `ProductId`, use the lowest `Order` value for the `ProductId` as the primary sorting key, and then use the specific `Order` value for that row as a secondary sorting key.

Comment: That's brilliant! Exactly what I need! Thanks a lot Damien

Answer (score 5):

It *nearly* sounds like you don't *really* want it sorted by order, primarily - you want it sorted by product ID and *then* order. So:

```
SELECT * FROM Products ORDER BY ProductId, [Order]
```

And in a LINQ query expression:

```
var results = from product in db.Products
              orderby product.ProductId, product.Order
              select product;
```

or:

```
var results = db.Products.OrderBy(p => p.ProductId).ThenBy(p => p.Order);
```

However, as noted in comments, that will give the wrong order for the last two lines.

If you're really after "use order as the primary key, but then hike any products in different orders within that group" then it's somewhat tricky. I'm not sure that what you're looking for is easily representable in SQL... `ORDER BY` really assumes you want your primary ordering to be a real primary ordering...

You could *try* this in LINQ - I don't know what the equivalent SQL would be, or whether it will actually work...

```
var results = db.Products
                .OrderBy(g => g.Order)
                .GroupBy(p => p.ProductId)
                .SelectMany(g => g);
```

In LINQ to Objects I *believe* that would work - but it's unclear whether it will in LINQ to SQL.

Comment: In your case `48` will be displayed before `59`

Comment: @praveen: That's true. It's unclear why that shouldn't be the case though - it seems that the OP doesn't really have a stable ordering in mind...

Answer (score 0):

I think you mean this -

```
SELECT * FROM Products ORDER BY [ProductId] ASC, [Order] ASC
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT * FROM Products ORDER BY ProductId, Order
```